# Angular JS nested buttons

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling with Angularjs filters (nested buttons).
I want to have three drop down menus where the content of the 2nd menu bases on the first menu, the text for the 3rd menu bases on the selection of menu 2. The text which should be displayed is indicated by "Level" information. 
My data structure is a JSON structure.

My idea is now:
1) for the 1st menu the user needs to select an item and based on this the ID_level is set to the first two numbers of the ID.
2) Based on the selection, a foreach loop searches in the values for Level-2 items which start with the same 2 digits at the ID-_level.
3) Then the content the second menu is shown.

For for some reason I have problems to access the selection of the first menu in my code, i.e. if I select "Goods" then I do not get any response for the level 2. The code for level 3 is not displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="View2.selection" >
  <option value="">---Please select---</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in View2.data1" value="{{option}}">{{option}}     </option>
</select><br>

<select ng-model="View2.selectionTwo" ng-change="View2.change(selection)">
   <option value="">---Please select---</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in View2.data2" value="{{option}}">{{option}}  </option>
</select>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
var values = [{ Name:'Goods', ID:'010000000000', Level:'1'},
 { Name:'Electronic good', ID:'010100000000', Level:'2'},
 { Name:'Coffee machine', ID:'010101000000', Level:'3'},
 { Name:'Water filter', ID:'010101030000', Level:'3'},  
 { Name:'Non-electronic good', ID:'010100000000', Level:'2'},
 { Name:'Hair care', ID:'010101000000', Level:'3'},
 { Name:'Cream', ID:'010101030000', Level:'3'}, 
 { Name:'Non-Goods', ID:'020000000000', Level:'1'},
 { Name:'Games', ID:'020100000000', Level:'2'},
 { Name:'Toys', ID:'020101000000', Level:'3'}];

var id_level1, id_level2;
self.change = function(selection) {
    /*Get selection from level 1 */
    this.selection=selection;

    /*Search in values for selected Item and get ID from level 1 */
    angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
     if (value.Level=='1') {
      if (value.Name==selection)    {
        id_level1=value.ID.substr(0,2)  
      }
     }
    }); 

    /*Push all items for level 1 to data2 whose data is then displayed next drop down*/
    self.data2=[];
    angular.forEach(values, function(value, key){
      var test=value.ID.substr(0,2);
      if (value.Level=='2' && test==id_level1) {
        self.data2.push(value.Name);
        id_level2=value.ID.substr(0,4);
      }
    });
};
```

Has anybody an idea how I could set this up in a working manner?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<select>` with angular, usually it's best practice to use `ng-options`. Check it out here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions